Mold behind drywall, replacement necessary or cleaning possible?
Having the homeowners worst possible nightmare: Window leaked and large parts of sheathing and even framing of a wall rotted. The entire exterior wall got demo'd to the studs, all framing exposed and all compromised wood replaced along with new windows, insulation and sheathing. In other words, compromised wood has been entirely replaced and the source of for the mold & rot is gone for good.
There is(was) mold behind the drywall too (actually much less than GM expected). GM recommends to replace drywall, but he says it's not absolutely necessary.
Note that neither the inside or outside of the wall showed signs of water intrusion, moist or even mold. The inner side of the drywall feels perfectly good and the drywall feels dry and in ok shape. The only visible sign was the baseboard under the window.
Further, the damage is due to winter rain. It hasn't rained for months and it's dry (California) and the drywall has also been exposed for days to full and direct sunlight.
Given the scope of the project exploded, I would really prefer not adding more time and material for drywall replacement, incl dependent work (molding, baseboards, painting). I just want to make sure that not replacing the drywall will not lead to any damage down the road.
This is the worst section (under the window):

You can see, the framing has already been repaired. There are other sections with spots of black mold but nothing which seems crazy to me.
Here is another part:

Finally, for reference a stud. I am not sure if this is a type of mold on it but according to my GM it's in great shape and structurally sound:

Back to the main question: Is it OK to brush off all the fungus and treat with vinegar or similar?

If all the drywall is solid and more stained than damage, then cleaning with protection should be enough.  Some of the bottoms do look on the iffy side, so double check those areas.  Replacing whole panels or a foot at the bottom is about the same amount of work.
